# How to get Google Plus login information from GTMOAuth2Authentication and GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch and set user as logIn in UIWebView

Tags: iphone, authentication, uiwebview, google-plus

**In my iphone application, I am using Google Plus SDK to sign in for my login page of app to allow user to login with google plus.But when user is in another View Controller and `when user is pressed button(Called Add on Google Plus) then i am opening UIWebView for searching people on google plus as` below:**

```
NSString *url_string =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://plus.google.com/u/0/s/%@/people",self.selectedMatch.realName];
NSString *urlEscaped = [url_string stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
UIViewController *webViewController = [[UIViewController alloc]init];
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,480)];
webView.scalesPageToFit= YES;
NSURL *nsurl = [NSURL URLWithString:urlEscaped];
NSURLRequest *nsrequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:nsurl];
[webView loadRequest:nsrequest];
[webViewController.view addSubview:webView];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:webViewController animated:YES];
```

But when this **webView is opened then user is no longer logged in**.`Web view is asking again to sign in to user.Any one know how to Logged in user in UIWebView.` Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried setting automatic sign in at the end of viewDidLoad? [signIn trySilentAuthentication];

Comment: Yes.I have tried but in UIWebView It doesn't work.